# How to dynamically change html button text with jQuery getting value from servlet?

Tags: jquery, html, button

I have several buttons in html, there is a pointer "Current_Id" point to them

And I have jQuery to get the pointer value from servlet, the jQuery code look like this :

```
      $.get('My_App?Action=Current_Id',function(data)\n"+
      {\n"+
        alert(data);\n"+
        var x='#Current_'+data;\n"+
        alert(x);\n"+
        $('Current_3').html($(this).text());\n"+
      document.getElementById('Current_6').innerHTML=$(this).text();\n"+
        $(x).html($(this).text());\n"+
       });\n"+
```

The html look like this :

```
    <Table border=1>
      <Tr>
        <Td><button id=Current_1 type=button style="width:78px;height:78px"></button></Td>
        <Td><button id=Current_2 type=button style="width:78px;height:78px"></button></Td>
        <Td><button id=Current_3 type=button style="width:78px;height:78px"></button></Td>
      </Tr>
    </Table>
```

My servlet is working properly, returning the Current_Id, I tried different ways to show text in the buttons : Current_1, Current_2, Current_3, but none works, what's the right way to do it ? I need help on correct syntax.

Comment: You can simply do $("#Current_6").text($(this).text());

Comment: I tried it, not working.

Comment: Check this : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/5nqh05b2/1/

Comment: Thanks for the sample, I tried the following :  $("#Current_1").text("Hello");
$("#Current_3").text($(this).text());
$(this).text($("#Current_1").text());  why only the first item works ?

Comment: Chances are $(this).text() is either empty or undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, the correct way to do it is :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $("#Current_2").text("Hello");
  var x='#Current_'+'3';
  $("button").click(function()
  {
    $(x).text($(this).text());
  });

});
</script>
```